# how to set a path to the static files which is surver independnet

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I have a master.html file which handles all my js and css files. The master files includes the css files with a relative path like

```
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

this way I don't have to provide the full path from root, which is survey specific. However, I noticed that this leads to trouble if I have a subtemplate like e.g.

```
website.com/profile/name
```

while it works fine for 'website.com/profile'. So now I am wondering how to avoid this problem without having to enter the entire path from root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

With the first `/`, you say that you're starting from the root, e;g:

```
website.com/static/css/bootstrap.css
```